# accessing dict in a tuple of tuple of tuples RDD

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a fairly complicated RDD data structure, for use in a pagerank algorithm (this is part of a homework problem):

```
[('4', (0.09090909090909091, ({'1': 1, '2': 1}, 2))),
 ('10', (0.09090909090909091, ({'5': 1}, 1))),
 ('3', (0.09090909090909091, ({'2': 1}, 1))),
 ('6', (0.09090909090909091, ({'2': 1, '5': 1}, 2))),
 ('7', (0.09090909090909091, ({'2': 1, '5': 1}, 2))),
 ('1', (0.09090909090909091, None)),
 ('8', (0.09090909090909091, ({'2': 1, '5': 1}, 2))),
 ('9', (0.09090909090909091, ({'2': 1, '5': 1}, 2))),
 ('2', (0.09090909090909091, ({'3': 1}, 1))),
 ('5', (0.09090909090909091, ({'4': 1, '2': 1, '6': 1}, 3))),
 ('11', (0.09090909090909091, ({'5': 1}, 1)))]
```

As part of the algorithm, I only need to change that float, but I do need to be able to access every part of the records. At the moment, I can get to the final tuple(s) with something like:

```
testRDD.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[1][1])).collect()
```

but at this point, I am unable to access the dictionary of second part of the tuple, either getting a NoneType error or, if using ast.literal_eval() I get a malformed node/string error. I understand why this might be but I'm still not sure how to access the dictionary and the value following it inside the tuple.

Comment: Isn't `x[1][1]` a tuple and `x[1][1][0]` a dict? I do not think you require `ast` module here

Comment: right, x[1][1] of the first record would be ({'1': 1, '2': 1}, 2)). But if I try x[1][1][1], I would get a NoneType error

Comment: You are getting error because of this `('1', (0.09090909090909091, None))` None cannot support index. Do filter and then perform map

Comment: Hmmm this is close to the solution, but I can't even do the filter due to the NoneType error, not sure how to fix this!

Comment: Any other ideas? I get a malformed node or string error if I try to apply ast.literal_eval()